# How to use .htaccess deny from all on subdirectory

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, web-hosting

My folder structure is like this

- `/home/user1/public_html/`
- `/home/user2/public_html/`

I want to place the .htaccess file at `/home/` and I only want to `deny from all` the `/home/user1/` directory.

I don't want to place the .htaccess file inside `/home/user1/`.

Is this possible?

Comment: try `Redirect 403 /user1` but not sure how it will behave, depends on your AllowOverride for the folder /home.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the httpd configuration files themselves, you should solve this in the config file, and not via .htaccess.

To deny access to a specific resource, use the  directive:

```
<Directory /home/user1>
    #for httpd 2.4, use: Require all denied
    deny from all
</Directory>
```